# max size a single pread can obtain

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am using pread to obtain huge amount of data at one time.

but If I try to gather a huge amount of data (for instance 100mb) and save it into an array I get a segfault....

is there a hard limit on the max number of bytes a pread can read?

```
#define          _FILE_OFFSET_BITS                            64 
#define          BLKGETSIZE64                                _IOR(0x12,114,size_t)
#define          _POSIX_C_SOURCE                             200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int readdata(int fp,uint64_t seekpoint, uint64_t seekwidth) {
    int16_t  buf[seekwidth];

    if (pread(fp,buf,seekwidth,seekpoint)==seekwidth) {
        printf("SUCCES READING AT: %"PRIu64"| WITH READ WIDTH: %"PRIu64"\n",seekpoint,seekwidth);
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("ERROR READING AT: %"PRIu64"| WITH READ WIDTH: %"PRIu64"\n",seekpoint,seekwidth);
        return 2;
    }

}





int main() {

    uint64_t    readwith,
                offset;
    int         fp=open("/dev/sdc",O_RDWR);

    readwith=10000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=100000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=1000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=10000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=10000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=100000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=1000000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=10000000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=100000000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=1000000000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=10000000000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=100000000000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=1000000000000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);

    close(fp);

}
```

Comment: I would say you are grabbing more than you want, and trying to read bytes further than the end of the file. This would explain segfault. Can you paste your code?

Comment: Are you sure that you called pread() with a buffer large enough for the data?

Comment: Are you reading into a stack-allocated buffer, or one allocated with `malloc`? The latter is a lot more reliable for really large buffers.

Comment: stack-allocated. I will post sample code later. as of right now it would be too long. I stack allocated because I don`t really want to deal with malloc if I dont have too...

Comment: The stack segment size is limited by the system, usually a few megabytes by default. What does `ulimit -s` output?

Comment: Probably no point to posting the code.  You are almost certainly blowing out the stack.

Comment: I added some sample code. it seg faults at a size of 10000000bytes. on my system. I am certain I am net going beyond EOF since it is a 2TB disk

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it outputs "8192"

Comment: Right so you blow up trying to read 10 megabytes into an 8 megabyte stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hard limit on the maximum number of bytes that [`pread`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) can read. However, reading that large an amount of data in one contiguous block is probably a bad idea. There are a few alternatives I'll describe later.

In your particular case, the problem is likely that you are trying to stack allocate the buffer. There is a limited amount of space available to the stack; if you run `cat /proc/<pid>/limits`, you can see what that is for a particular process (or just `cat /proc/self/limits` to check for the shell that you're running). In my case, that happens to be 8388608, or 8 MB. If you try to use more than this limit, you will get a segfault.

You can increase the maximum stack size using [`setrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) or the Linux-specific `prlimit`, but that's generally not considered something good to do; your stack is something that is permanently allocated to each thread, so increasing the size increases how much address space each thread has allocated to it. On a 32 bit system (which are becoming less relevant, but there are still 32 bit systems out there, or 32 bit applications on 64 bit systems), this address space is actually fairly limited, so just a few threads with a large amount of stack space allocated could exhaust your address space. It would be better to take an alternate approach.

One such alternate approach is to use [`malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) to dynamically allocate your buffer. Then you will only use this space when you need it, not all the time for your whole stack. Yes, you do have to remember to `free` the data afterwards, but that's not all that hard with a little bit of careful thought in your programming.

Another approach, that can be good for large amounts of data like this, is to use [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to map the file into your address space instead of trying to read the whole thing into a buffer. What this does is allocate a region of address space, and any time you access that address space, the data will be read from that file to populate the page that you are reading from. This can be very handy when you want random access to the file, but will not actually be reading the whole thing, you will be instead skipping around the file. Only the pages that you actually access will be read, rather than wasting time reading the whole file into a buffer and then accessing only portions of it.

If you use `mmap`, you will need to remember to `munmap` the address space afterwards, though if you're on a 64 bit system, it matters a lot less if you remember to `munmap` than it does if you remember to `free` allocated memory (on a 32 bit system, address space is actually at a premium, so leaving around large mappings can still cause problems). `mmap` will only use up address space, not actual memory; since it's backed by a file, if there's memory pressure the kernel can just write out any dirty data to disk and stop keeping the contents around in memory, while for an allocated buffer, it needs to actually preserve the data in RAM or swap space, which are generally fairly limited resources. And if you're just using it to read data, it doesn't even have to flush out dirty data to disk, it can just free-up the page and reuse it, and if you access the page again, it will read it back in.

If you don't need random access to all of that data at once, it's probably better to just read and process the data in smaller chunks, in a loop. Then you can use stack allocation for its simplicity, without worrying about increasing the amount of address space allocated to your stack.

**edit to add**: Based on your sample code and other question, you seem to be trying to read an entire 2TB disk as a single array. In this case, you will definitely need to use `mmap`, as you likely don't have enough RAM to hold the entire contents in memory. Here's an example; note that this particular example is specific to Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2)
        errx(1, "Wrong number of arguments");

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        err(2, "Failed to open %s", argv[1]);

    struct stat statbuf;
    if (fstat(fd, &statbuf) != 0)
        err(3, "Failed to stat %s", argv[1]);

    size_t size;
    if (S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        size = statbuf.st_size;
    } else if (S_ISBLK(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        if (ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &size) != 0)
            err(4, "Failed to get size of block device %s", argv[1]);
    }

    printf("Size: %zd\n", size);

    char *mapping = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (MAP_FAILED == mapping)
        err(5, "Failed to map %s", argv[1]);

    /* do something with `mapping` */

    munmap(mapping, statbuf.st_size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does mmap handle block device? since its unbuffered at it seems what does it do if I for instance read something smaller than the blocksize?

Comment: @user3021085 A block device itself is not unbuffered; in fact, what "block device" means is that I/O to it is buffered via the page cache. When you do any sort of reading from it or writing to it, that goes through the page cache. When you mmap it, it is mapped in page-sized increments; anything beyond the range of the actual underlying file will be set to 0. So, you can read or write smaller increments, but all of the actual I/O will go through the page cache, in page-sized chunks.

Comment: all right thanks. I will try to use mmap then as even with malloc it fails... I posted a different question for it

Comment: @user3021085 Ah, yes, if you're trying to access an entire 2TB disk as a single contiguous array, `mmap` is the way to go.